# EJS not installing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying install ejs in my project and its first time i am doing so.
I tried several commands but none of them seem to work.

Some Commands that i tried are given below :

```
npm i ejs
npm i ejs --save
npm i ejs -g
```

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "ejs" under a package
npm ERR! also called "ejs". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

What could be causing this and how can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json` you likely named your project "ejs", in which case it gives an error like that, rename your project to something else then try install ejs again.